# Authentication Failed - Web Connector (Consolibyte PHP Quickbooks integration)

Tags: php, api, soap, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to establish a connection to our webapp with quickbooks desktop through web connector. However, when I try updating through web connector, I'm getting authentication failed message. We're using consolibyte's  quickbooks PHP integration and simply trying to get the example_web_connector_minimal.php file to work.

Here is our .qwc file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>PNW-SS</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>https://beta.helphog.com/quickbooks-php/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_minimal.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription>Gateway to WebApp</AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>https://beta.helphog.com</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{A9A83089-7DA7-4d27-A08C-7E1626E9395A}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{AE931E67-4AA5-4374-A32D-8EA4BEC91981}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

Here's the respective PHP file

```
<?php

/**
 * Example QuickBooks Web Connector web service
 * 
 * This is a minimal example of using the QuickBooks Web Connector. Make sure 
 * you look at docs/example_web_connector.php for more details. 
 * 
 * MAKE SURE YOU READ OUR QUICK-START GUIDE:
 *  http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector_quickstart
 *  http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks
 * 
 * @author Keith Palmer <keith@consolibyte.com>
 * 
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

// I always program in E_STRICT error mode... 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

// We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}

// Require the framework
require_once '../../QuickBooks.php';

// A username and password you'll use in: 
//  a) Your .QWC file
//  b) The Web Connector
//  c) The QuickBooks framework
$user = 'quickbooks';
$pass = 'password';

// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
    // ... more action handlers here ...
    );

// This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is returned by QuickBooks
$errmap = array();

// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array();

// Logging level
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        // Use this level until you're sure everything works!!!

// * MAKE SURE YOU CHANGE THE DATABASE CONNECTION STRING BELOW TO A VALID MYSQL USERNAME/PASSWORD/HOSTNAME *
$dsn = 'mysql://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
    
    // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
    
    // Queueing up a test request
    $primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
}

// Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
// __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);

/**
 * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular customer to QuickBooks
 */
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:
     
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                        <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
    
    return $xml;
}

/**
 * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    return; 
}
```

As stated before, web connector throws this error: [image]

And when we open up to see the log in VERBOSE, the following is stated:

```
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'PNW-SS' has STARTED
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: PNW-SS
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): PNW-SS
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://beta.helphog.com/quickbooks-php/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_minimal.php
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.3.0.215">
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'PNW-SS', username = 'quickbooks'
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Response is not well-formed XML.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20220916.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

I'm not quite sure how else I'm supposed to format the XML or if that is even the issue.

When visiting the endpoint in browser:

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>/home/regiuzkk/beta.helphog.com/quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Driver/Sql/Mysql.php</b> on line <b>289</b><br />
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>/home/regiuzkk/beta.helphog.com/quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Driver/Sql/Mysql.php</b> on line <b>289</b><br />
QuickBooks PHP DevKit Server v3.0 at /quickbooks-php/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_minimal.php
   (c) "Keith Palmer" <keith@consolibyte.com> 
   Visit us at: http://www.ConsoliBYTE.com/ 

Use the QuickBooks Web Connector to access this SOAP server.

QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server::handle() parameters: 
 - $return = 1
 - $debug  = 1

Misc. information: 
 - Logging: 4
 - Timezone: America/New_York (Auto-set: )
 - Current Date/Time: 2022-09-16 17:50:07
 - Error Reporting: 32767

SOAP adapter: 
 - QuickBooks_Adapter_Server_Builtin

Registered handler functions: 
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => authenticate
    [2] => sendRequestXML
    [3] => receiveResponseXML
    [4] => connectionError
    [5] => getLastError
    [6] => closeConnection
    [7] => serverVersion
    [8] => clientVersion
)

Detected input: 


Timestamp: 
 - 2022-09-16 17:50:07 -- process 0.0365
```

There are no other errors in the PHP errorlog

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that the version of the PHP integration is compatible with your version of quickbooks? The `mysql` deprecated message and incorrect XML has my first instinct being you're using a different version where the expected XML has changed.

Comment: That got it to work! I didn't realize PHP versions differ in their XML format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob pointed out, PHP versions differ in their XML format. The version of PHP I was using (5.6), had an outdated XML format therefore an update to PHP version 7.2 was required.